# Searching if a directory exists within a folder

Tags: files-and-directories, searching

I hope this question is not a duplicate, but I could not find any other question which answered my specific question, which is:

I have the following folder structure (just an example):

samefolder/A01/122/AB 
samefolder/A02/123/A 
samefolder/A03/124/AB 
samefolder/A04/125/AB 
samefolder/A05/126/A

I just want to have the path from the directories where the AB folder is, i.e. A01/122, A03/124, A04/125.

I tried it likes this, but I'm stuck right now:

```
SetDirectory["samefolder"]
folders = Select[FileNames[], DirectoryQ[#] &]
```

which gives me the names of the folder A01 to A05, but that's not really what I want. I only want the names of the folders, where the AB exists (A01/122 and so on).

I appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the MMA file inside `"samefolder"` directory then:

```
 SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

StringTake[#, {1, -4}] & /@ FileNames["*AB", "", Infinity]

(*{"A01\\122", "A03\\124", "A04\\125"}*)
```

Comment: You don't need to put the notebook in the "samefolder" if your write instead : `FileNames["AB","absolutePathTosamefolder",Infinity]` where "absolutePathTosamefolder" is the absolute path to your "samefolder"

Comment: Thank you all. The solution of SquareOne  worked for me, though I did use a level of 3 rather than Infinity.